# Что будет если внедрить одну и ту же зависимость два раза?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Почему при двойном вызове AddTransient для одного объекта получается ошибка типа Unable to resolve service for type?

Comment: заголовок выглядит как вопрос, а текст - как ответ))

Comment: А как вы добавляете? Если просто класс по несколько раз, то это.... Странно, ибо зачем дубликат в контейнере? У вас должен быть интерфейс, который реализуют нужные вам классы, а затем уже добавляете в контейнер `<IMyInterface, MyType1>`, `<IMyInterface, MyType2>` ... Вот в таком случае, большинство контейнеров без проблем добавят все, а если надо получить все объекты, то запрашиваете коллекцию (`IEnumerable<IMyInterface> items`). Ну а если у вас один класс, который должен создаваться с разными параметрами - делайте фабрику и ее уже добавляйте в контейнер.